# Converting Date Into a specific text format in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013

Ok so i have been trying to do this and i pretty much keep on failing :p

Basically what i want to do is take the date 10/1/2013 and turn it into 201310. I tried to concatenate using left and right. tried to make it into text using left and right. Nothing seems to be working. The closest i got was to 20130 by using `=CONCATENATE(TEXT(J3,"mmyyyy"))` Which turned the date into 102013 than i tried  `=RIGHT(L3,4)*LEFT(L3,2)` and got 20130 which is still incorrect. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply turn around your first example and use the correct string:

```
=TEXT(J3, "yyyyMM")
```

Note, I used upper case `M`. Lower case `m` means minutes, while upper case `M` means month.
The `CONCATENATE` is unnecessary.

Please also note, that this is prone to localization issues, i.e. it depends on the language settings. I am from Germany and I need to use `jjjj` instead of `yyyy`.

Comment: Ahh thank you so much bro! it worked! i didnt think just doing that would make a difference i thought concatenating it was necessary.